# Why is the silverlight datagrid loaded event not firing in my ViewModel when I think it should?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am working in silverlight 5 using caliburn.micro and wanted to do execute code to resize columns after a grid bound via ItemsSource was done loading.

The loaded event for both a DataGrid and C1FlexGrid won't fire until I visit the screen, leave it, then go back.  If I subscribe to the Loaded event in a non-mvvm/non-caliburn.micro project, the loaded event fires when I expect it to (right away).

Right now all I want to do is resize the columns but this problem worries me for future coding - can I not count on control events working as expected when using Caliburn.Micro? Why is the loaded event firing when it is? Is there a workaround that would allow me to execute code when an event is supposed to fire?

In the loaded callback it is easy to resize the columns - here is a snippet of what I am doing in Caliburn.Micro ViewModel:

```
Page3View currentView = null;
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
{
    base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    currentView = (Page3View)view;

    //neither of these get fired until I look at the page, navigate away, then come back again.
    currentView.gridC1.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(gridC1_Loaded);
    currentView.gridNormal.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(gridNormal_Loaded);
}

void gridNormal_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String testStr = ""; testStr += "some pointless code to break on";
}

void gridC1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentView.gridC1.AutoSizeColumns(0, currentView.gridC1.Columns.Count - 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Based on the symptoms it sounds like the grids Loaded event is getting fired before the OnViewLoaded event does and thus your eventhandlers haven't been attached yet. Any reason you aren't attaching the eventhandlers in your constructor instead?

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that. That's where I started attaching but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc not firing. Handlers attached after first `Load` event fired.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here